# In ASP.NET MVC are Controller and Model completely stateless?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've tried to create a simple hello world asp.net mvc app with this requirement: It has an input box which is number. The user can change the number value, if ever the value is text instead of a number, the webpage should show the previous number entered.

The problem is I can't a way to do so as it seems that Controller and Model are stateless. Am I right? Does it mean for mocking even such simple case I have to setup a database?

Comment: You can just store original value in a hidden field - no need for database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use Sessions in MVC, just declare it in the attributes of the class (not only readonly, you can change that):

```
namespace NamespaceName {
    [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
    public class ClassName : Controller {

        public ActionResult MethodName(string param) {
        // CODE HERE
        }

    }
}
```

Then you'll have access to HttpContext.Session.

Answer (score 2):

Controller and model are stateless and you could possibly work this around by involving session or any other server-side persistence mechanism but why bother?

Instead, make the client stateful - add some javascript code that validates the input and restores the previous value if the validation fails. Then, only upon succesfull client-side validation, post the form to the server.